# Cross-platform renderer on iOS: control the main loop from C++ class

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I’m porting my OpenGL-based renderer (written in C++) to iOS and ran into the following problem:

On Windows my renderer-class has a _renderProject (e.g. a game I’m making) and a _view object that again has a GLFW window. I do my loop in the renderer as follows:

```
void Renderer::runRenderer()
{
   while (_running && _view->isRunning())
   {
       draw((_view->getTime() - _initialTime));
   }
}
```

The draw function looks like this:

```
void Renderer::draw(double currentTime)
{
    [...]
    // Call loop function of the project
    if (_renderProject)
        _renderProject->loopFunction(currentTime - _elapsedTime, currentTime);
    [...]
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing for iOS but I don’t know how to do the loop in the renderer class. 
I would like to use CADisplayLink but I don't know how to call a C++ memeber function from there.

**UPDATE**

Following the code written by @Kazuki Sakamoto I changed my code to this:

```
/* Main Loop using CADisplayLink */

typedef void (^block_t)(double);
@interface RendererCaller : NSObject
{
    CADisplayLink *_displayLink;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) block_t updateBlock;
@end

@implementation RendererCaller

- (void)start:(block_t)block
{
    self.updateBlock = block;
    // check whether the loop is already running
    if(_displayLink == nil)
    {
        // specify update method
        _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update:)];

        // add the display link to the run loop (will be called 60 times per second)
        [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }
}

- (void)stop
{
    // check whether the loop is already stopped
    if (_displayLink != nil) {
        // if the display link is present, it gets invalidated (loop stops)
        [_displayLink invalidate];
        _displayLink = nil;
    }
}

- (void)update:(CADisplayLink *)sender
{
    double time = [sender timestamp];
    updateBlock(time);   /// ERROR, it doesn't know "updateBlock"
}

@end

/* Renderer */

void Renderer::runRenderer()
{
    if (_rendererCaller == nil) _rendererCaller = [[RendererCaller alloc] init]; 
    [_rendererCaller start:^(double time) {
            this->draw(time);
        }];
}

void Renderer::stopRenderer()
{
    [_rendererCaller stop];
}

void Renderer::terminateRenderer()
{
    stopRenderer();
    _rendererCaller = nil;
    [...]
}

void Renderer::draw(double time)
{ 
    [...]
    if (_renderProject)
        _renderProject->loopFunction(time - _elapsedTime, time);
    [...]
}
```

I get an error in the following line: updateBlock(time);

**UPDATE 2**
I had to change it to `_updateBlock(time);` for some reason but now it works! Thank you so much! You really made my day today :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Create a Objective-C class to call C++ method.

For example, Cocos2d-x created `CCDirectorCaller` Objective-C class in Objective-C++ source code (.mm file).

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/platform/ios/CCDirectorCaller-ios.mm

**ADDED**

You want to use `CADisplayLink` for the OpenGL ES render loop. And you also want to use your C++ main loop. Right?

`CADisplayLink` needs `NSRunLoop`. Also it needs an Objective-C object, for `target` and `selector`. Thus, you must create at least one Objective-C class for `CADisplayLink`.

See also [Friday Q&A 2010-01-01: NSRunLoop Internals](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-01-nsrunloop-internals.html).

So, there is the main `NSRunLoop` with `CADisplayLink` in the main thread. Infinite loop in the main `NSRunLoop` is not totally good idea because `NSRunLoop` can't loop due to the infinite loop. It is obvious. Thus, if you really want to use your C++ main loop, you should create a thread.

```
      The main thread                  Other thread

       +-----------+                   +-------------+
       |           |                   |             |
       V           |                   V             |
the main NSRunLoop |                C++ main loop    |
       |           |                   |             |
       |     CADisplayLink             |             |
       |       call target's method    |             |
       |           |                   |             |
       |           |                   |             |
       +-----------+                   +-------------|
```

And if you want to use `CADisplayLink` schedule for rendering, you need to implement some rendezvous thread synchronization pattern between the main `NSRunLoop` and your C++ main loop.

It's complicated enough. That's why I recommend you to create a Objective-C class to call C++ method, not C++ main loop.

> I had to make the draw function of the renderer public and the renderer class itself singleton

Not really.

```
// **pseudo code**

// In Objective-C++ source code
typedef void (^block_t)(double);
@interface RendererCaller : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) block_t updateBlock;
@end

@implementation RendererCaller
- (void)start:(block_t)block
{
    self.updateBlock = block;
    CADisplayLink *link = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update:)];
    ...
}
- (void)update:(CADisplayLink *)sender
{
    updateBlock(elapsed time using sender);
}
@end

void Renderer::startMainLoop()
{
    RendererCaller *rendererCaller = [[RendererCaller alloc] init];
    [rendererCaller start:^(double elapsed){
        this->draw(elapsed);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like in the link you posted they do it the same way I already do it: The director is singleton and director->mainLoop() is a public function call. That's exactly what I don't want. Only the renderer should call draw(), otherwise I could get an infinite loop.

Comment: Then create your own thread with the mainloop that cooperates with CADisplayLink in the main runloop.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that. Could you explain what kind of thread I could create in my renderer class and how it can cooperate with CADisplayLink? Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. The second thing is what I was going for (I don't want to use my C++ loop). Problem is: I really don't get the code since I'm quite new to iOS. I just copied most of it and get an error in this line: `updateBlock(elapsed time using sender);` What does this "using" mean and what do I have to do to get it running?

Comment: I updated my initial post so you can see what I changed. If we get this to work you'll have made my day and probably the whole week ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted "elapsed time using sender", I thought "using" was some kind of keyword and this was actual code (since it got colored in XCode). Now it works, after I changed `updateBlock(time);` to `updateBlock(time);`. I don't really get why that worked, but it totallay works now :-D Thank you so much! This really helped me a lot.